# Ember data - set belongsTo to null

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following models:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    profile: DS.belongsTo('profile')
});
App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
    item: DS.attr()
});
```

I want to remove the profile from the user, but the profile itself should not be deleted. I tried:

```
var user = this.modelFor('user');
user.set('profile',null);
user.save();
```

However, the `PUT` to `/user/{id}` still contains the profile-id. How do I remove the relationship for this specific object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case profile_id is sent as nil. If you want to completely remove profile from the user model extend or reopen your serialiser and just skip profile if it is nil.